# audio stream for a web site

Tags: ros, web, audio

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm looking for a nice way to stream the audio collected from the robot mics to a web interface. Is any one aware of a ROS project which already provides that kind of functionality?  Something similar to the [mjpegcanvasjs](https://github.com/rctoris/mjpegcanvasjs) in the [Robot Web Tool](http://robotwebtools.org) but with audio data. Image+audio would work too.
Thanks.

---

Edit: Thanks luketheduke! you are right, more details might help to better understand the problem: we want to develop a web-based remote interface for controlling a robot. The operator will be sit in front a computer far from the robot (even in a different network) and he/she should be able command the robot, and to see and to hear what the robot sees and hears. The robot runs ROS indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.

ffmpeg looks like an option but I have some doubts: 1. Ideally we'd like to stop and start the streaming of audio and video on demand. Using ffmpeg, we'll have it running endlessly and I'm concerned about the required resources. 2. Besides, we'll use a web-based interface (html) so right now I'm not sure if the audio streaming provided by ffmpeg can be played through a web. Any comments??

The idea is to end up with a ROS package that could be deployed in any robot to stream audio.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262621/audio-stream-for-a-web-site/) by [Álvaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3882/%C3%A1lvaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What about this ?

http://wiki.ros.org/webrtc_ros

WebRTC is used for simple Audio/Video communication between peers using a browser.

Just an idea, using standards.

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2017-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0